# Как проверять на пустоту сессию в java spring?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Как в java spring MVC проверить на наличие сохраненной сессии?
К примеру на php я делал так:

```
if(!$_SESSION['a']) $this->redirect('bla bla')
```

А как примерно такую же вещь сделать с сессией на spring MVC?

Answer (score 0):

Если я Вас правильно понял, смотрите в сторону HttpSession , например:

```
String sessionUserId = httpSession.getAttribute("USER_ID") != null ? httpSession.getAttribute("USER_ID").toString() : "USER_UNDEFINED";
```

Атрибуты можно получить :

```
httpSession.getAttributeNames()
```

Также время последнего обращения, айди сессии и многое другое.
Если речь идет о контроллерах, то добавьте в параметры, например:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Services/getData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ResponseEntity<String> getData(@RequestParam(value = "param", required = true) String param, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession httpSession) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Получите `Id` сессии из `HttpServletRequest request` в вашем контроллере:

```
request.getSession().getId()
```

И проверьте на его нахождение в вашем списке сессий.